# Changing password in mysql database using php is not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();


$current_pass = $_POST['currentpassword'];
$new_password = $_POST['newpassword'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirmpassword'];

$current_pass = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['currentpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND hash='$hash'");

if(!$result){
    echo"User doesn't exist!!";
}
else{
    //Make sure form is submitted with post method
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        //See if password equals currentpassword
        if($_SESSION['pass'] == $_POST['currentpassword']){

            //See if newpassword equals confirmpassword
            if($_POST['newpassword'] == $_POST['confirmpassword'] ){

                $new_password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

                $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$new_password' WHERE email='$email'";

                if( $mysqli->query($sql)){
                echo "Your password has been reset successfully!!";
                }
            }   
            else{
                echo "Passwords don't match. Please enter again";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Wrong Password. Please Enter again";
        }

    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RESET PASSWORD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Reset your password</h1>
        <form action="reset.php" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Enter Current Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="currentpassword" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Enter New Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="newpassword" autocomplete="off">
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
                Confirm New Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <a href="profile.php"><button class="button button-block"/>Change Password</button></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is showing error Notice: Undefined index: currentpassword in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login-system\reset.php on various lines and is also showing Wrong Password. Please try again although I am entering the right password.

Comment: please print the content of `$_POST` array.

Comment: Show your form also

Comment: shared the html form

Comment: where is your query for get `$email` for set password

Comment: are you talking about the $result query??